# How to add `<Extensions>` element in SAML request using passport-saml?

Tags: node.js, saml, saml-2.0, passport-saml

I am using [passport-saml](https://github.com/node-saml/passport-saml) as a SAML client and requesting to external IDP. I want to add `<Extensions>` element in SAML request like below:

```xml
<samlp:AuthnRequest AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://iam.test.fi/oxauth/postlogin" Destination="https://testidp.fi/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO" ID="_3a5525fc-f5cc-46af-add6-70bbc27ecebf" IssueInstant="2021-05-19T11:05:04Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
<saml:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://iam.test.fi/oxauth/1</saml:Issuer>

<samlp:Extensions>
<vetuma xmlns="urn:vetuma:SAML:2.0:extensions"><test>fi</test></vetuma>
</samlp:Extensions>

<samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true"/>
<samlp:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact">
<saml:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://testidp.fi/2017/loa3</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

I checked [passport-saml config parameters](https://github.com/node-saml/passport-saml#config-parameter-details) but didn't find any one which gives facility to add `<Exntesions>` element.

Thank you.

Comment: I sure hope you find something. The best I could find was this pull request from 5 years ago that never made it past review: https://github.com/node-saml/passport-saml/pull/147